Wake from "Modern Standby" not consistent (SetWaitableTimer)
I maintain a Windows service that runs in session 0. It performs maintenance tasks at certain times in a similar way to the Windows task scheduler. If the system is asleep, it uses SetWaitableTimer() to wake-up. This has worked well for traditional sleep and hibernate for many years.
The widespread adoption of "Modern Standby" has broken this code. Modern standby isn't a traditional sleep state but rather seems to be a special system idle state. In this state, the OS is still running, services in session 0 are heavily throttled and most other user programs are suspended. Apparently, this increases battery life and gives a phone-like user experience. Interestingly, many built-in OS apps seem to be exempt from the throttled/suspend behaviour.
On a system with modern standby, SetWaitableTimer() fires as normal (although sometimes a little late) and the service code briefly runs again. However, this only lasts a few seconds and then the service is throttled again. The service cannot do any useful work in this brief period.
NB: During this brief period, the screen does not turn on and the OS does not send a resumed notification like PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC or similar.
I have tried the following techniques to fully wake-up the system from this state:

Attempt to force system awake. This doesn't work:
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED)

Attempt to turn on display using:
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, (LPARAM) -1);


This doesn't work from a service running in session 0.

Turn on display using a proxy process - Similar to above, but running in the current console session (e.g. not session 0). This works but the process is launched suspended and doesn't run until the next time the system is manually resumed. Consequently, this technique doesn't work either.

Please, is there a way to force the system to fully "wake-up" from modern standby without user intervention?

"is there a way to force the system to fully "wake-up" from modern standby without user intervention?" - not really. See Modern Standby and Modern Standby wake sources

One solution is to create virtual keyboard kernel driver and simulate a (user) key press to wake-up. This is how the MSFT PwrTest tool works. From a system perspective, this is the same as real user input. However, this is an extreme technique. I'm hoping there is a simpler way.

That makes me wonder if SendInput() would work, or be ignored? It uses the same input queue as physical devices. But the events are marked, so easily distinguishable.

I tried it. It didn't work. I this is because it happens at a much higher level in the API stack. Also, SendInput() in session 0 is ignored. This is expected. SendInput() in the console session may work but any process that could send it is either suspend or launched suspended whilst the system is in modern standby. This is apparently because all "normal" (user) processes are a member of a job object that is used for the process suspension or throttling. There seems no way to escape this without a kernel driver (which I am currently working on)
